# Developing a Code Library

Tags: productivity, libraries

So I am in the middle of making (and maintaining) my own code library with quick snippets to make life easier.

I'm assuming a lot of other people do this to help.

My question is, what sort of things do you store in this so called library

Also, Do you use any tools to organise this library?

Comment: You _will_ learn that creating a good library is hard.  How will you need to use any given non-trivial function in years to come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this to be a great program for managing different code snippets:

http://www.flexiblelearning.com/ssbk.htm

*"The Scripter's Scrapbook is a fully-featured cross-platform personal reference library, source code repository and information organizer that integrates the convenience of the desktop with the resources of the web."*

I am not affiliated with this at all, just thought it was cool.  I've actually set my sights on making my own.

Comment: Looks nice. Maybe I should go about developing my own ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have various libraries. Each library has its own subject, such as mathematics, hashing, security, bit manipulation. As I program in different languages and not all code is portable, I just tend to keep those libraries near the developing environment, as they clutter up quickly.

*Contents*
Each library consists of one or more well commented and well named functions. They range from Counting the number of set bits in a 32bit int, to deriving some unique machine id from the network interfaces and corresponding MAC addresses.

*Storage*
Projects (this is handy in .NET environments, you can load them everywhere) and compiled libraries (.dll).